# Delayed HTTP Request in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm curious. I just tried to delay a HTTP Request in Angular (6.x) with `.pipe( delay( 5000 ) )...` but it looks like, that RxJS just delays the final response not the server call. But I really need to delay the real server call. That wasn't a problem in AngularJS via HttpInterceptor but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Thx in advance.

Update:

I already tried the HttpInterceptor but that doesnt work either. I have a CustomHttpClient which puts running request urls in an array and removes them after its done. Some request cannot run in parallel so I've to check the list for pending calls from e.g. /api/somePath. If such an url is in the list the current request has to be delayed. Works fine within the HttpInterceptor of AngularJS.

Comment: windows.setTimeout( () => { /* Your delay code */ }, 5000)

Comment: Why you want to delay the http call ??

Comment: @DeependerSharma probably to avoid rate limits

Answer (score 8):

I like those interceptors, because you can do a lot of magic with them.

Handle the RESPONSE of a http call in the interceptor

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(response=> console.log(response) )  // <== or do some other magic
    );
  }
}
```

Handle the REQUEST of a http call in the interceptor for example delaying it.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return timer(2000).pipe(         // <== Wait 2 Seconds
      switchMap( ()=> next.handle(request) )   // <== Switch to the Http Stream
    )
  }
}
```

in both cases it´s the same "intercept(...)" Method, but different handling of the  "next.handle()".

warm regards

Answer (score 3):

If you want to delay the call itself with RxJS you can use `timer`:

```
timer(5000)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(() => of(42)),
  )
  .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: You don't need `take(1)`, `timer(5000)` emits once and resolves.

Answer (score 2):

Start with a different observable (in this case a timer observable) and switch to your http client observable:

```
timer(1000).pipe(
 switchMap(() => this.http.get('')),
)
.subscribe();
```

or

```
of(null).pipe(
 delay(1000),
 switchMap(() => this.http.get('')),
)
.subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can, again, use a `HttpInterceptor` from `@angular/common/http` do to that for you.

Or just:

`Observable.timer(5000).pipe(tap(
    // do your stuff
))`

Comment: I already tried  the `HttpInterceptor` but that doesnt work either. I have a `CustomHttpClient` which puts running request urls in an array and removes them after its done. Some request cannot run in parallel so I've to check the list for pending calls from e.g. `/api/somePath`. If such an url is in the list the current request has to be delayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RxJS `Observable.timer`

```
let myRequest = this.http.get(...);
let pollingSubscription = myRequest
 .expand(() => Observable.timer(5000).flatMap(() => myRequest))
 .subscribe();
```